# VB.net Could not find type 'AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Using visual studio 2015 after I published the app it gives the following error. I tried removing the Windows Media Player reference then adding it again but it didn't work. How to solve the following error?

[image]

Comment: Not much information to go on here... Have you tried changing the target platform to see what happens? (x86, x64, AnyCPU)

Comment: yes I did that but It did not produced any error after that.